# Speech Recognition in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

So I have speech recognition working, but the problem is it only works in Chrome. After searching around I have seen many people saying that speech recognition works now in Firefox but some saying it doesn't. What is the clear answer?

[This](https://codeburst.io/html5-speech-recognition-api-670846a50e92) website states that

> It is July 2018, and the WebSpeech API is still a working draft and
>   only available in Chrome and Firefox.

I have added `window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;`

I have `media.webspeech.recognition.enable` enabled in Firefox.

But nothing works.

Here is an example of my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5cm8ypg/

Comment: read the [caniuse note 2](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition) ... *Firefox currently has a media.webspeech.recognition.enable flag in about:config for this, **but actual support is waiting for permissions to be sorted out*** - other parts of the speech API (not the recognition part) are available in firefox

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API#Browser_compatibility there is no support for Firefox (but for some versions of Edge). Last update in [February 2019](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/blob/master/api/SpeechRecognition.json).